# Pillow ImageGrab.grab() not working on a virtual machine

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, kvm

I'm trying to take a screenshot on a virtual machine I have. The virtual machine is hosted on a fedora 37 server using kvm and the virtual machine I'm running it on is fedora 37 workstation. Whenever I try to take a screenshot using PIL I get OSError: error 8

I tried

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,400,400), xdisplay=":0")
print(img)
```

and to verify I used

```
echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

When I try to run the code I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File = "/home/notimportant/Programming/ScreenTesting/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,400,400), xdisplay=":0")
  File = "/home/notimportant/Programming/ScreenTesting/venv/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py", line 80 in grab
    size, date = Image.core.grabscreen_x11(xdisplay)
OSError: X get_image failed: error 8 (73, 0, 1310)
```

Which I'm assuming I get this because it's a virtual display, but I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people who are like you had a same error in the past. According to the `asweigart` in my [reference](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5130).

> This is definitely an issue of Pillow not working on Wayland. I made
> one change in my Ubuntu 21.10 vm: modifying /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to
> uncomment #WaylandEnable=false and then ran sudo systemctl restart
> gdm3 to restart it so Ubuntu is using X instead of Wayland. Both
> ImageGrab.grab() and the mss module's screenshot function worked
> perfectly.

This is his snippet:

```
#Open this file.    
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf

#Modify this value
WaylandEnable=false
```

Then, do this command to apply the option.

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```